# List of all possible wifis not working?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

I'd like to get a list of all possible wifis I can connect to. I've been using `nmcli` with `nmcli dev wifi` to do so. On my Linux Mint machine this works fine, but on raspbian I don't get any results. I don't know why or what I have to do.

I already set my country code in the `wpa_supplicant.conf` and wifi isn't blocked by rfkill.

`$ iwlist wlan0 scan` returns `wlan0     No scan results`.

`$ ifup wlan0` returns `ifup: unknown interface wlan0`.

Comment: I don't think `ifup`  is what you want - that deals with interfaces configured in /etc/network/interfaces ... which you don't want to mess with

Comment: you probably want `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` or `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID` to get just the SSID's - note the `sudo`

Comment: @JaromandaX On my Pi this works fine without the `sudo`

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - doesn't on any one of my 7 pi's with wifi - without sudo, shows current connection only, with sudo shows all available

Answer (score 1):

`ifup` will not work with wireless, you should rather use `iwconfig wlan0`.

On my system, `sudo rfkill unblock 0` followed by `iwlist wlan0 scan` works fine. There's no need for `sudo` in the second command. It could be that you have installed several network managers at the same time, or using the wireless interface in AP mode.

Comment: so, without sudo, you get a list of all available SSID's?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I do. You don't?

Comment: No - that's why I suggested it in the comment to the question!